# Is there a way to add repulsion to each particle as they are being pushed or collided together?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, 3d-view, particles

When you collide or push multiple spheres (particles) together like in the image they will be symmetric or lopsided depending on the number of spheres. If a repulsion could be added to each particle as they are being pushed together the symmetry would smooth out. This would be very helpful for another physics project I am working on.
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the Self Effect particle settings? Using a Force in there should repel all particles from each other.

Comment: This is a behaviour that can also be managed with boids.

Comment: Would it be possible to walk me through it step by step? Or a link to a video? Thank you

Comment: @BillAlsept - What have you got so far? How are you setting up the particles and getting them to collide? Or are you using something other than particles (such as Rigid Body)?

Comment: @RichSedman I have only asked two questions on blender and in the other question there was an answer that had the program And setup you are asking about. That question was answered by vklidu.

Comment: Ah, I see. There is no automatic link between questions and questions - it would be useful if you could edit your question to include additional description (eg, that it’s rigid body rather than Particles) and a link to your other question.

Comment: @RichSedman I will see what I can do. I just meant click on my name and you will see my other question where I was given the setup that I am using now. I do believe it has rigid body. Thanks